# Ruby-- Split entries in an array into separate entries with a custom delimiter

Tags: ruby

I have an array containing multiple values, some of which I wish to split into separate entries.

```rb
array = [ 'foo', 'frob & baz', 'bar' ]
# I want to split these with ' & ' as a delimiter, to get this output:
result = [ 'foo', 'frob', 'baz', 'bar' ]
```

I would prefer to avoid having to explicitly enumerate through the array.

Comment: _"I would prefer to avoid having to explicitly enumerate through the array"_ – what do you mean by that?

Comment: Avoiding methods like each(), those which create loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to solve this problem without iterating over the array. You have to inspect each element of the array to check whether it contains the delimiter. No matter how you slice and dice it "inspecting each element" is just another way of saying "iterate over the array".

The way I would approach it, is to [`map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Array.html#method-i-map) over all elements of the array, and [`split`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/String.html#method-i-split) them by the delimiter:

```ruby
array.map { _1.split(' & ') }
#=> [['foo'], ['frob', 'baz'], ['bar']]
```

As you can see, this gives us almost the desired result, there is just an extra level of nesting, which we can remove with [`flatten`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```ruby
array.map { _1.split(' & ') }.flatten(1)
#=> ['foo', 'frob', 'baz', 'bar']
```

However, [the combination of `map` and `flatten` is wasteful and not very intention-revealing](https://rubystyle.guide/#flat-map). There is a standard method which exists in almost every collection library in almost every language which does exactly what we need: [`flat_map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```ruby
array.flat_map { _1.split(' & ') }
#=> ['foo', 'frob', 'baz', 'bar']
```

If we were using [Rubocop](https://rubocop.org/), it would [warn us about this](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-performance/cops_performance.html#performanceflatmap) (using the optional [*rubocop-performance* extension](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.57/extensions.html#official-extensions)) and even auto-correct it for us!

Comment: Could you explain your use of `_1.split` rather than `|e| e.split`? I couldn't find any documentation on your method, and am interested to know more.

Comment: @Zopolis4 It is a concept called numbered parameters. Instead of explicitly using ordinary parameters, you can just use the those positional arguments. The  `_1` is just the first parameter to the block function.
You can read more on that here: https://medium.com/@baweaver/ruby-2-7-numbered-parameters-3f5c06a55fe4

Answer (score 1):

You can split an members of an array into separate entries in that array by first joining it using the delimiter which you want to split the members by, then splitting it using that delimiter.

```rb
array = [ 'foo', 'frob & baz', 'bar' ]
result = array.join(' & ').split(' & ')
```

Comment: `array.flat_map { |e| e.split(' & ') }` is also an option.

Comment: Is there any practical reason why you want to avoid methods that iterate the array? IMHO, @muistooshort's version is way easier to read and to understand than your version. And it is likely faster too.

Comment: I agree with you, but they didn't post it as an answer, so I can't accept it.

Comment: Your answer violates the restriction in your question, as `Array#join` *does*, in fact, "enumerate through the array". In fact, your problem is *impossible to solve* without iterating through the array. You have to look at each element to check whether it contains the delimiter.

Comment: I was trying to avoid *explicitly* enumerating through the array-- so avoiding methods which used .each, or similar.